# JUnit 5 testing problem with injection null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

I would like to come to you all because a month ago I started working with JAVA/SPRING and today I started unit testing from JUnit 5.

Here are my codes:

```
package com.tracker.EsportTracker;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class EsportTrackerApplicationTests {
    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("before all Method");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        System.out.println("after all Method");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeTest() {
        System.out.println("before test Method");
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterTest() {
        System.out.println("after test Method");
    }

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("Starting Test");
        TestUser testUser = new TestUser();
        testUser.getUsers();
        System.out.println("End Test");
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.tracker.EsportTracker;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import com.tracker.EsportTracker.entities.User;
import com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.impl.UserService;

@SpringBootTest
public class TestUser {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @Test
    public void getUsers() {
        System.out.println("userService =" + userService);
        List<User> users = userService.findAll();
        assertNotNull(users);
        
        for (User user : users) {
            assertNotNull(user.getUsername());
            assertFalse(user.getUsername().isEmpty());
        }
    }
}
```

After following the JUnit documentation while keeping it as simple as possible for the moment, a problem with the injection occurred.

```
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
```

I was able to import the requested service but the "userService" service remains null
In the documentation they even said to add this to make the service visible throughout the application :

```
@ComponentScan("com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.impl")
```

```
package com.tracker.EsportTracker;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.impl")
public class EsportTrackerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EsportTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

thank you in advance for your help

annexe :

```
2023-12-20T14:27:16.181+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-12-20T14:27:16.252+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.7.Final
2023-12-20T14:27:16.255+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-12-20T14:27:16.438+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-12-20T14:27:16.582+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-12-20T14:27:16.602+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-12-20T14:27:16.867+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@12f8682a
2023-12-20T14:27:16.869+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-12-20T14:27:16.914+01:00  WARN 10568 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
2023-12-20T14:27:17.179+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-12-20T14:27:17.833+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-12-20T14:27:17.965+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-12-20T14:27:18.340+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
2023-12-20T14:27:19.080+01:00  WARN 10568 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-12-20T14:27:19.723+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5a429813, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@348b26e0, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@61cf142f, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6a2d1f6d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@12b0440b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6298dafb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@62d10834, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@795d43d9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@26ab3c1b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@78f2cab9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5c902a83, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6af447b6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@98dc042, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3e1ba156, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@641bd93e]
2023-12-20T14:27:19.769+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [           main] c.t.E.EsportTrackerApplicationTests      : Started EsportTrackerApplicationTests in 5.215 seconds (process running for 6.337)
before test Method
Starting Test
userService =null
after test Method
after all Method
2023-12-20T14:27:20.275+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-12-20T14:27:20.277+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-12-20T14:27:20.289+01:00  INFO 10568 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: Your test doesn't make sense. Your `TestUser` is created by you bypassing all test enrichment that `@SpringBootTest` adds.

Comment: I'm still learning...just trying to understand how it works. It would be best to be a little more constructive in your answers or let someone else answer. Just because something seems simple to you doesn't mean it's simple to others.